# Drag & Drop application in Java like IDesignerHost in .Net

Tags: c#, java, drag-and-drop

I have an application built in .net which uses IDesignerHost. The most important part of this application are drag & drop feature, moving controls in the designer and showing all the horizontal & vertical alignment lines automatically, saving the design in database (I am saving all the imp properties on the controls) and then reloading it automatically when the design is selected (I pick up all controls and their properties from database)

Now I have a requirement to build the same application in Java. I am not a profi in Java. When I googled, I could only find simple drag & drop using SWT or other in Java. But not like what IDesignerHost would provide. Can someone give me the lead?

Note: IDesignerHost will allow you to provide your own Forms Designer in your application. Using this you can built an application that is much similar to Visual Studio too. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13272/Crafting-a-C-Forms-Editor-from-scratch

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: NetBeans with Swing components?

Answer (score 1):

[Window Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) maybe ? Integrated in eclipse since Indigo.

Comment: I need to develop something like this. But it wouldn't save the design in .java file, instead in database. Do you know using which interface this application is being built?